# Gun shooting in cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I just started to learn Cocos2d programming for iphone and have a question about shooting imitation in Cocos2d. I have a *sprite*. When I drag it to the other place and drop it, I want to start shooting permanently in one direction with another little sprite named *shell*. So I need to repeat forever a two-step-loop in -ccTouchesEnded:

1.*shell* starts to move away from *sprite*(imitation of shooting)(CCMoveTo);

2.when *shell* stops(it's range of movement is limited)it should disappear or should be turned invisible.(removeChild:, visible: or what?)

And it needs to repeated forever(CCRepeatForever actionWithAction[CCSequence actions:];

So, I need help to set an eternal cycle of these two actions.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are asking. I'll try to help you with what I do understand though.

When you want to remove the shells, just set them invisible. Calling **addChild:** and **removeChild:** all of the time will cause your device to cry.

Instead, at the start of your game, create a fixed amount (maybe 15 - 20) depending on your needs and store them in an array. Set them all invisible. Then, every time you need a shell, get one that isn't being used, set it visible, and apply an action to it. When you don't need it anymore (when it stops) just set it invisible.

If you could elaborate a bit more then I would be glad to try and answer the rest of your question :)

EDIT:

In your .h file, create an NSMutableArray named shells. Initialize it. Create an int (bulletIndex = 0) Then call at beginning of your app:

```
- (void)createBullets {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        CCSprite *shell = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"shell.png"]; //Create a sprite
        shell.visible = NO; //Set it invisible for now
        [self addChild:shell]; //Add it to the scene
        [shells addObject:shell]; //Add it to our array
    }
}
```

Now your touchesEnded: method:

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self schedule:@selector(shootingTimer:) interval:1.0f]; //This schedules a timer that fires the shootingTimer: method every second. Change to fit your app
}
```

The method we scheduled above:

```
- (void)shootingTimer:(ccTime)dt {
    CCSprite *shell = (CCSprite*)[shells objectAtIndex:bulletIndex]; //Get the sprite from the array of sprites we created earlier.
    shell.visible = YES; //Set it visible because we made it invisible earlier
    //Do whatever you want to with a shell. (Run your action)
    bulletIndex++; //Increment the index so we get a new shell every time this method is called
    if (bulletIndex > shells.count - 1) bulletIndex = 0; //We don't want to go out of our arrays (shells) bounds so we reset bulletIndex to zero if we go over
}
```

Then, if you want to turn this off on touchesBegan:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self unschedule:@selector(shootingTimer:)];
}
```

Finally, as far as the actions for your shells go, you are going to want to do something like this:

```
id shellMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration: yourDuration position: yourPosition]; //Move it to wherever you want
id shellEnd = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget: self selector:@selector(endShell:)]; //This will call our custom method after it has finished moving
id seq = [CCSequence actions:shellMove, shellEnd, nil]; //Create a sequence of our actions
[shell runAction:seq]; //Run the sequence action
```

The endShell method may look like this:

```
- (void)endShell:(id)sender {
    CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)sender;
    sprite.visible = NO;
}
```

Hopefully this explains most if not all of your problems. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: A set seems to be more appropriate for your solution than an array.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, mates. allthewayapps - post is now edited, is it became more clear for understanding?

Comment: Don't worry about. I commend you for being able to speak what you can. It's better than I can do. I'll take a look at your edited post.

Comment: Please see my edit. @JustSid I added your suggestion into my answer. Actually, no. You will want to use an array, not a set.

Comment: allthewayapps Thank you so much for editing and super detailed answer! I tried to do all like you recommend, but now I have warning 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' after I drop *sprite*. Now I try to figure why this warning is, because all looks fine

Comment: Change if (bulletIndex > shells.count) bulletIndex = 0; to: if (bulletIndex > shells.count - 1) bulletIndex = 0; Sorry about that and you are very welcome, glad I could help.